# Serialize in Java and read in C++

Tags: java, c++, serialization, binary

I am trying to serialize a Java object in such a way that its content can be read by an existing **reader.cc** module, which currently reads binaries generated in C++.

The following is a snippet from **reader.cc**, where it reads 3 variables (`name_len, fname, and feature_names_count`):

```
uint32_t name_len;
in.read((char *)&name_len, sizeof(uint32_t));          

char *fname = new char[name_len + 1];
in.read(fname, sizeof(char) * name_len);           
fname[name_len] = '\0';

uint32_t feature_names_count;
in.read((char *)&feature_names_count, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

This is what I am doing in Java, where the 3 variables that I am serializing (and reading from **myObject**) are of type `int, String, int` (I tried each of the commented methods):

```
    private static void createBinaryFile(TestClassToSerialize myObject) throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File(PATHNAME);
        myFile.createNewFile();
        writeObjectToFile(new FileOutputStream(myFile), myObject);
    }

    private static void writeObjectToFile(FileOutputStream fos, TestClassToSerialize myObject) throws IOException {
        fos.write(intToByteArray(myObject.getNameLen()));
        fos.write(myObject.getFname().getBytes());
        fos.write(intToByteArray(myObject.getFeatureNamesCount()));
        fos.close();
    }

    public static byte[] intToByteArray(int data) {
        return Ints.toByteArray(data);
    }
//    public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
//        return new byte[] {
//                (byte)(value >>> 24),
//                (byte)(value >>> 16),
//                (byte)(value >>> 8),
//                (byte)value};
//    }

//    public static byte[] intToByteArray(int data) {
//        byte[] result = new byte[4];
//        result[0] = (byte) ((data & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
//        result[1] = (byte) ((data & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
//        result[2] = (byte) ((data & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
//        result[3] = (byte) ((data & 0x000000FF) >> 0);
//        return result;
//    }
```

These are the values that are read from **reader.cc**: *251658240, _Z9test_loopPii, 4294967295*;
These are the values that I am instead serializing: *15, _Z9test_loopPii, 4*;

I also tried storing the digits as `long`, and then using the following method to serialize it to bytes:

```
public static byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
        buffer.putLong(x);
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer.array(), 0, 4);
    }
```

But, when I deserialize in C++, I get the same values that I get from the other code (the one that serilizes integers).

I can't change the C++ code, but I can do whatever I want in the Java one, even store data in different formats in **myObject**.

Do you have any suggestion?

Here are the links to the repositories containing the above-mentioned code (they are both OSS), in case some context might help: [reader.cc](https://github.com/usi-systems/freud/blob/master/freud-statistics/reader.cc), [Java code](https://gitlab.software.imdea.org/nicola.amadio/freud-java-serialization/-/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java).

Comment: Did you try using a hex editor to dump the contents of the binary file in hexadecimal, and figure out exactly how the Java code is writing the data to it, and compare it to what your C++ code expects to read? If you did you'd have your answer in just a few seconds.

Comment: @RichardCritten I would like to but I don't want to modify the C++ system.

Comment: "It's not working" is not enough information. Without modifying the C++ you can at least debug it and see what values it reads vs what you expect?

Comment: `unit32_t` is 32-bit. You write 64 bit (a `long`).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you're right. I remember using the long and then only taking 4 bytes (which didn't work either) and then smh ended up here. Do you recommend any particular way to serialize a Java int/long to make it compatible for unit32_t?
EDIT: I tried looking up SO for this first, but none of what I found seemed to work for me.

Comment: Rather than doing your custom serialization, have you thought about using Base64?

Comment: Which 4 bytes did you take? The first four or last four?

Comment: @atomSmasher the last 4 (the first 4 didn't work either). Just updated the question.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ language has `std::getline`, overloading operators and functions.  In the C language, you have variables named `class`.  Are you mixing languages?  Please update your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: @NicolaAmadio Looks like now you messed up the byte order - Big endian vs little endian. (Basically, you have to reverse the bytes of the byte array when writing ints)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it works now, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The key was to serialize the int/long correctly.

I chose to use an `int` because it had 32 bytes, same as `uint32_t` on reader side. It was enough to take the bytes in it and reverse it (because of big endian vs little endian, thanks Johannes Kuhn for the suggestion).

Here's the method:

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int data) {
        byte[] bytes = Ints.toByteArray(data);
        ArrayUtils.reverse(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
```

I used Guava to get bytes out of the integer (`Ints.toByteArray`), but there were also other ways to do this, like the ones commented out in the question (just reverse the bytes array in addition to that).

Comment: An other way than reversing the array is by modifying the `intToByteArray` to produce the array in the right order.